# listview in android: one activity it applied to all the listview items

Tags: android, listview, webview

In our project, for the listview items it is getting linked to the same content.but we need to give diifferent activities to all the listview items..for example: If we click History listview it is opening the related history activity..but the same history activity is opening for all the listview items..plz help to resolve.

java code:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class OurSchool extends ListActivity{

 String[] listItems={"History", "Mission And Objectives", "Principals Forewords", "School System", 
         "Calender", "Rules And Regulations", "Our Traditional", "Our Alumini Council","Our Pholosophy","Our Branches"};
 boolean[] listImages= {true, true, true, true, true,true, true, true, true, true};


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.our_school);
        setListAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, R.layout.our_school, R.id.text1, R.id.image1, listItems, listImages ));
        this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    final int pos, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), History.class);
                String product = null;
                // sending data to new activity
                i.putExtra("product", product);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }


    }
```

History.java:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class History extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.history);   

        mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        mWebView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/History.html");     

    }
}
```

history.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="About :LITTLE FLOWERS PUBLIC SCHOOL"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you,

Comment: What you need ?? Here all your activity having webview or diffrenet things..>???

Comment: Just to be clear, you have all the other activities but History.class and OurSchool, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass listViewItem Position to NextActivity.

```
 @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int pos, long id) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), History.class);
            // sending data to new activity
            i.putExtra("pos", pos);
            startActivity(i);
        }
```

Then your nextActivity will be look like

```
public class History extends Activity {

WebView mWebView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.history);   

    int pos = getIntent().getIntExtra("pos",0);      

    mWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.setBackgroundColor(0);
    mWebView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    switch (pos) {
    case 0:
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/History.html");
        break;
    case 1:
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Objective.html");
        break;
    case 2:
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Principles.html");
        break;
    case 3:
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Calender.html");
        break;
    case 4:
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ShcoolSystem.html");
        break;

    default:
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/History.html");
        break;
    }    

  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to change your logic a bit. Becasuse in the present code you are using only History.class in the Intent. Thats why its opening for every list item. You might have to change the class name based on the item clicked.

for example

```
String item = (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
Intent i;
if(item.equals("History")
  {
  i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), History.class);
  } 
  else if("Mission And Objectives")
  { i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AnotherClass.class);}
```